# Бот не отправляет Pdf файл после конвертации

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Пытаюсь конвертировать фотки, которые юзер отправляет боту в чат, а бот отправляет их в одном pdf файле.
Не понимаю на какой стадии кода появляется ошибка, так как сам Питон никаких ошибок не выдает.
Я еще учусь, возможно проблема очевидна, но я ее не вижу. Помогите и обьясните пожалуйста)

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from config import Token_API
import im2pdf
import os


bot = Bot(Token_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def on_startup(_):
    print('Я онлайн!!!')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text=f'{message.from_user.first_name}, Начало работы')
    await message.delete()


# Путь к временной папке для сохранения фотографий
TMP_DIR = 'tmp'

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def handle_photos(message: types.Message):
    # Создаем временную папку, если она еще не существует
    if not os.path.exists(TMP_DIR):
        os.mkdir(TMP_DIR)

    # Сохраняем принятые фотографии во временную папку
    photo = message.photo[-1]
    photo_path = os.path.join(TMP_DIR, f'{photo.file_unique_id}.jpg')
    await photo.download(destination_file=photo_path)

    # Отправляем пользователю сообщение о том, что фотография сохранена
    await message.reply(f'Фотография сохранена: {photo_path}')

    # Если приняты все фотографии, конвертируем их в PDF и отправляем пользователю
    if len(message.photo) == message.photo[-1].file_size:
        # Собираем пути к сохраненным фотографиям
        photo_paths = [os.path.join(TMP_DIR, f'{photo.file_unique_id}.jpg')
                       for photo in message.photo]

        # Конвертируем фотографии в PDF
        pdf_path = os.path.join(TMP_DIR, f'{message.message_id}.pdf')
        im2pdf.convert(photo_paths, pdf_path)

        # Отправляем пользователю файл PDF
        with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            await bot.send_document(message.chat.id, pdf_file)

        # Удаляем временные файлы
        for path in photo_paths:
            os.remove(path)
        os.remove(pdf_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp,
                           skip_updates=True,
                           on_startup=on_startup)
```